# Can a virtual machine created in Windows run on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, vmware-player

I created a virtual machine (Windows 7 64-bits) on VMware in my former OS - Windows 10.

Now I'm using Ubuntu and my question is, can I use the VM created in W10 in my Ubuntu machine?

I have a few projects running on Windows 7 and it would be very good if I could use the same VM.

Happy 25th birthday, Linux!

Comment: It should work.  I have no experience with VMWare, but I have done this in VirtualBox. I see no reason why it wouldn't work for VMWare.  That said, it is often easier to export a virtual machine from the original installation, and then import it on the new machine.  VMWare surely has tools for that.  (Quick Google gives me this for an older version: https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-D1FEBF81-D0AA-469B-87C3-D8E8C45E4ED9.html )

Comment: Also keep in mind that such fundamental underlying changes might screw up Windows 7 activation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can easily run any VMware VM in Ubuntu. Just copy their files to Ubuntu drive and start using it.

If you have any problem in accessing to your Windows 10 drives, just simply restart your Windows 10 to resolve the issue.